# Computing the sign of an integer using C and assembler

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, assembly

This is my assignment:

For each of these questions, you must write a C (not C++) program that contains three parts:

A. Some C code to read inputs (using scanf).

B. A segment of inline-assembler to do the computation.

C. Some C code to write the output (using printf).

2. sign.c : reads a single integer, uses assembler to compute its sign (-1, 0, or 1), and outputs the sign. You will need opcodes jge and je.

I was able to do the first question (adding 2 integers, using those same 3 guidelines), but now I am stumped on this one.

I am able to get the first part of this particular question working (comparing eax and 0, then jumping to DoIF), but when I uncomment the other parts, the computation is messed up.

Thank you in advance for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"


    int v; //integer to be read
    int sign; //sign

    int main()
    {
    printf("Enter an integer to compute its sign.\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &v); // this is how you read an int from the user

    //sign = -(v < 0); //C version
    __asm // tell MS Visual studio to start a block of assembler
    {

    mov eax, v // load x into A
    cmp eax, 0 // compare A with value 0
    je DoIF // if comparison was = 0, jmp to DoIF
    mov eax, 100
    mov sign, eax
    jmp done

    //mov eax, v; // load x into A
    //cmp eax, 1; // compare A with value 1
    //jge OtherIF; // if comparison was = 0, jmp to DoIF2
    //mov eax, 2;
    //mov sign, eax;
    //jmp done;

    //mov eax, v; // load x into A
    //cmp eax, -1; // compare A with value 1
    //jle NextIF; // if comparison was <= 0, jmp to DoIF3
    //mov eax, 100;
    //mov sign, eax;
    //jmp done;

    DoIF:
    mov eax, 0; // do y = 1
    mov sign, eax;

    /*OtherIF:
    mov eax, 1;
    mov sign, eax;*/

    /*NextIF:
    mov eax, -1;
    mov sign, eax;*/

    done:
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jl`(jump less) or `jge`(jump greater equal), if you have to jump if the result of comparison is less than `0`:

```
int v; //integer to be read
int sign; //sign

printf("Enter an integer to compute its sign.\n");
scanf_s("%d", &v);

__asm 
{
    mov eax, v    // load x into A
    cmp eax, 0    // compare A with value 0
    je equal0     // if comparison was == 0 then jmp to equal0
    jge greater0  // if comparison was >= 0 then jmp to greater0
    mov eax, -1   // set eax to -1
    mov sign, eax // sign = -1
    jmp done
equal0:
    mov eax, 0    // set eax to 0
    mov sign, eax // sign = 0
    jmp done 
greater0:   
    mov eax,  1;  // set eax to 1 
    mov sign, eax // sign = 1
done:
}

printf("signe of %d is %d.\n", v, sign );
```

Comment: Rabbid76, it won't let me tag you. The only problem with your answer is that I HAVE to use JGE as well as JE (otherwise your answer is fine). Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, with fewer instructions (avoiding the unconditional branches):

```
    ;; Input in input_val.
    ;;  If it's already in a register, use test reg,reg instead of cmp
    xor    eax, eax
    cmp    input_val, 0
    je  .input_was_zero
    setg   al               ; eax = 0 (input_val<=0)  or  1 (input_val > 0)
    lea    eax, [eax*2 - 1] ; eax =-1 (0-1)           or  1 (2-1)
.input_was_zero:
    mov    [sign], eax      ; store eax somewhere since MSVC inline asm can't just tell the compiler that the result is live in eax
```

The key point is that **you only need one test** against zero.  Checking two of the `g`, `ge`, `e`, `le`, or `l` conditions will gives you all three cases based on that one comparison.

---

This also avoids your silly `mov reg, imm` / `mov [mem], reg` sequence, (where you should have used `mov [mem], imm`, since having the value of `sign` in eax at the end of the inline asm does no good.)  However, my code gets the values from `setcc`, rather than `mov reg, imm` anyway.  (And of course [zeroing a reg is done with xor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and), which avoids a slowdown when reading the full reg after using setg on the low byte.)

I was going to do a slightly more straightforward implementation with setg and then a conditional branch to skip over a `mov eax, -1` or a `dec` or something, but then I noticed I could save even more instructions with `lea` to map `(0,1)` to `(-1,1)`.

I also avoid loading `input_val` into a register, since `cmp mem, imm` works fine to get the flags set based on the comparison, and is more efficient than a separate load and `test eax,eax`.